# Is this a worm or snake?How to get rid of it?

Tags: entomology, herpetology, pest-control, snake

[image]

Hi! I found this thing in my bathroom. I killed it but still it's friends keep on reappearing. It moves slowly , is it a snake? How can i get rid of them? I live in Mumbai, India. It's rainy season here and the size of animal varies from 5 cm to 15 cm approximately.

Comment: This animal moves slowly. Have a look at this video https://youtu.be/IDhxsmuRq3w

Comment: If it's dead you should be able to get some closer pictures? (Looks to skinny to be a snake, but really hard to see anything)

Comment: Hi! I just got a clear video of its young relative. Can you tell me what is it? https://youtu.be/gOsNf-jtppM